# About exec() function and time

Tags: php, time, exec, limit

I'll show some code, first:

`echo exec("compile\\save.exe Untitled.c tmpUntitled.c");`

I have a program, named `save.exe` and i want to know if it already stopped?
If stopped, ok... Do something...

If not, may be an error, or a loop... 
Now: I want to build same way to control the time that program use, and put a limit (time limit exceed, something like this...)

Any one has a sugestion ?

**Edit[1]:**`save.exe` is a program wrote on C language, and use two parameters: source and destiny.
`popen` just don't execute `save.exe`, i say this because it don't gerenate anymore the destiny (with `exec`it happens);

Comment: Exec won't do it. Use `popen`, which is asynchronous.

Comment: See also stream_select to enforce the time limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec()` will suspend your script while the exec'd program is running. Control will be returned only when the external program terminates. If you want to see if the program's hung up or waiting for input or somesuch, you use [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen), which returns a filehandle from which you can read the program's output. At that point you can do a polling loop to see if there's been any output:

```
$app = popen("your shell command here");

while($output = fgets($app)) {
   // handle output
   sleep(5); // sleep 5 seconds
}
```

If you want to send something to the app as input, then you have to use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open), which allows bi-directional communication between your script and the external program.